# Regex finding more than one time pattens in string with R

Tags: regex, r, time

Say, if I have such a string:
`03:30-12:20, 12:30-15:0015:30-18:00`
and i need to break them into an array:
`03:30` `12:20` `12:30` `15:00` `15:30` `18:00`

Can anyone suggest what regex and R function I should use to do so?
Thanks!

Comment: Looks like `\d{2}:\d{2}`. There is a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions someone is marking duplicate whenever someone asks a regex question without showing effort.

Comment: probably not a duplicate but generally regex questions seem to be "suggest me a [regex] tool" with no effort shown

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
regmatches(string, gregexpr('\\d\\d:\\d\\d', string))
[[1]]
[1] "03:30" "12:20" "12:30" "15:00" "15:30" "18:00"
```

Notice that the colon is always surrounded by four digits. We repeat that pattern with the special regex character `\\d` which means digit. `[0-9]` is used in the other answer and is just as good, if not better for advanced regex tokenizing operations. I used `\\d` to show other avenues to the same goal.

You can also specify how many digits should be matched with curly braces. In this case, 2 digits is what we're looking for around colons,

```
regmatches(string, gregexpr('\\d{2}:\\d{2}', string))
[[1]]
[1] "03:30" "12:20" "12:30" "15:00" "15:30" "18:00"
```

Answer (score 2):

I contributed a regex solely for this in the [**qdapRegex**](http://trinker.github.io/qdapRegex_dev/) package.

```
library(qdapRegex)
x <- '03:30-12:20, 12:30-15:0015:30-18:00'
rm_time(x, extract=T)[[1]]
# [1] "03:30" "12:20" "12:30" "15:00" "15:30" "18:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
regmatches(input,gregexpr('\\d{2}:\\d{2}',input))
```

OR

```
strsplit(gsub("(\\d{2})(?=\\d{2})","\\1 ,\\2",input,perl=T),',|-')
```